# I have a NAS drive connected to my sky home network this is where I store my emails

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a NAS drive connected to my sky home network this is where I store my emails.

I have just got an EE device (mobile internet) to use when I am away caravaning the problem is I don't want to take my NAS drive as it only connects through rj45.

What I would like is to buy a drive to take my emails and be able to connect wirelessly to either my home network or the EE mobile network when away.

I have looked around and cannot find a wireless drive that can do this for use with Windows 8 and also a tablet, the drive only needs to be 500gb.

Note: [EE](https://ee.co.uk/) is a UK mobile and fiber broadband provider.

Comment: What is an EE network?

Comment: @Richie086 [EE](https://ee.co.uk/) is a UK mobile and fiber broadband provider. I've added that to the question.